# Running a process remotely using Python

Tags: python, scilab

Is it possible to run a System process remotely , i.e. in the background using python?

For e.g. I ave Scilab installed on my system, now I do something like this

```
                 xx= os.system('scilab-adv-cli')
```

in the python console. But this fires up an actual scilab command line interface. Though I need something like this :

```
                  xx.add(1,2)
```

here is some function predefined in scilab module whic on invoking should return 3 here. CAn this be done?

Comment: I think you're looking for subprocess. It will allow you to feed STDIN and receive STDOUT from scilab-adv-cli. http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

If this is limited to Scilib, check out http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/sciscipy/

which should let you do everything scilib can do from within python.

Also, while this doesn't solve your problem, you should considering using subprocess instead of os.system

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Comment: In other words:
1) Use python bindings if they exist for your package
2) Otherwise, use subprocess to communicate with an external command

Comment: 3) `pexpect` can be a useful tool for communicating with interactive (text-mode) programs locally or remotely.